# How to lock the screen in XFCE?

Tags: 14.04, xfce

How do I lock the screen in XFCE? I mean I have `xflock4` enabled to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> combination but that locks/mutes it all including running applications like music players. When I click *Lock screen* on Cairo Dock it does what I want.

Is there a command I should add to *Keyboard shortcuts* menu?

Comment: It should be `Ctrl + Alt + L` IIRC

Comment: it's `xfce` not `unity` or whatever you use. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

With help of Cairo Dock *Shortkeys* menu I could configure the lock.

[image]

To install Cairo Dock:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```